# unclear how to get single vector of predictions from multivariate ARX in Statsmodels

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, statsmodels

As a disclaimer, I have very limited experience with using time-series models.

I am attempting to train an ARX model a year's worth of hourly energy data for a set of 23 buildings. I expect to get a single vector of predictions, given a set of timestamps that are within the training data. From this I can validate against my testing data that covers a subset of the same timestamps.  I am attempting to use [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/vector_ar.html) as a VAR(p) model to do an initial attempt before adding in my exogenous terms. I presume this is a VAR model, as it is multivariate per timestamp. My attempt to use VARMAX with order(3,0) to create a VARX model resulted in a very long running model that did not work, so I fell back to a simple VAR model first.

My end goal is to fit a VARX model with the dataset below, as well as the average of each hour as the exogenous term. I would expect this would result in a single vector of parameters with a length equal to the lag term. I then would use this to predict a single vector of `y_hat` predictions for each row in my training data set. I can then compare the output of this to a subset of the the same hours from my testing data set.

My training dataset of normalized hourly energy data looks like the following (forgive the formatting after `bldg5`, it didnt copy well):

```
start_time          Bldg1               Bldg2               Bldg3               Bldg4                    Bldg5               Bldg7  Bldg8   Bldg9   Bldg10  Bldg11  Bldg12  Bldg13  Bldg14  Bldg15  Bldg16  Bldg17  Bldg18  Bldg19  Bldg20  Bldg21  Bldg22  Bldg23 
2014-01-05 00:00:00 0.2345679012345679  0.08234295415959253 0.02127659574468085 0.006535947712418301    0.3939393939393939  0.020325203252032523    0.034013605442176874    0.11003236245954694 0.013307984790874526    0.013513513513513514    0.06734006734006734 0.02840909090909091 0.3116883116883117  0.5301204819277109  0.03793103448275862 0.058064516129032254    0.3546511627906977  0.009523809523809523    0.47887323943661975 0.9228571428571428  0.04154302670623146 0.2773109243697479
2014-01-05 01:00:00 0.2345679012345679  0.07045840407470289 0.07092198581560284 0.006535947712418301    0.3939393939393939  0.04065040650406505 0.03741496598639456 0.07119741100323625 0.020912547528517112    0.013513513513513514    0.03367003367003367 0.02840909090909091 0.5194805194805195  0.4487951807228916  0.020689655172413793    0.06451612903225806 0.4476744186046512  0.009523809523809523    0.5014084507042254  0.6914285714285714  0.03560830860534124 0.2605042016806723
2014-01-05 02:00:00 0.2345679012345679  0.07555178268251274 0.056737588652482275    0.026143790849673203    0.3636363636363636  0.020325203252032523    0.03741496598639456 0.07119741100323625 0.011406844106463879    0.013513513513513514    0.04377104377104377 0.02840909090909091 0.4675324675324675  0.4728915662650603  0.017241379310344827    0.05161290322580645 0.436046511627907   0.009523809523809523    0.4732394366197183  0.66    0.03857566765578635 0.13165266106442577
2014-01-05 03:00:00 0.2345679012345679  0.07045840407470289 0.02127659574468085 0.006535947712418301    0.25757575757575757 0.036585365853658534    0.03741496598639456 0.07119741100323625 0.020912547528517112    0.010135135135135136    0.037037037037037035    0.02840909090909091 0.4285714285714286  0.39457831325301207 0.020689655172413793    0.08387096774193549 0.19767441860465118 0.006349206349206349    0.47887323943661975 0.7771428571428572  0.04154302670623146 0.16246498599439776
2014-01-05 04:00:00 0.2345679012345679  0.07045840407470289 0.02127659574468085 0.006535947712418301    0.2727272727272727  0.02845528455284553 0.030612244897959183    0.06796116504854369 0.011406844106463879    0.010135135135135136    0.03367003367003367 0.0625  0.3766233766233766  0.009036144578313253    0.020689655172413793    0.1032258064516129  0.0872093023255814  0.009523809523809523    0.49295774647887325 0.19714285714285712 0.03264094955489614 0.12324929971988796

. . .
```

Testing dataset (also normalized hourly energy data) looks like the following (shape 168x1):

```
TestTime            TestBldg
2014-09-07 00:00:00 0.09427609427609428
2014-09-07 01:00:00 0.037037037037037035
2014-09-07 02:00:00 0.0404040404040404
2014-09-07 03:00:00 0.037037037037037035
2014-09-07 04:00:00 0.037037037037037035
. . .
```

when I fit a a model like the following:

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR
var_mod = VAR(train_norm.iloc[:,3:])
var_res = var_mod.fit()
var_res.summary()
```

I get a lag coeff for every building in my dataset, which is unexpected. I also do not understand how to do a prediction on my fit model, `var_res`, as I would expect to do a `var_res.predict()` as you do with the univariate of AR, `AutoReg()`

(aside: what is the difference between forecast and predict functions in statsmodels. What is the difference between predict in the model before fitting, ie. `var_mod` and the fitted model, `var_res.predict()` ?)

Please let me know what additional clarifications I can provide.

Comment: writing this out made me think, do you simply take the average of the all the building coeffs for each our and then use those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general VAR model allows for an effect of any of the `K` states within the previous `p` timesteps (using statsmodels' notation). It sounds like what you want is not necessarily VECTOR autoregression at all (b/c you don't want one building to rely on the previous timesteps of another building) but rather just an AR model using a "panel" dataset (multiple timeseries observations). I'm sure there is a way to do this in statsmodels, but honestly a quick search did not yield one. You could always construct your own version as a standard OLS model by pivoting the dataset so that each observation is a buildingXtime observation, and then creating new features that are the lagged energy uses from `t-1` to `t-p`. Then you could simply run OLS on that. But there is probably a function to do this in sm that I am missing.

As for your predict/forecast question, `predict` looks like it is a method of the `VAR` object (`var_mod` in your code) rather than `VARResults` (`var_res` in your code), and requires you to specify parameters. So this relies on your in-sample data and seems to only be able to accept prescribed parameters rather than use your fitted parameters. If you wanted to, you could do something like

```
var_mod.predict(var_res.params, start=train_norm.index[p], end=train_norm.index[-1], lags=p)
```

But I think what you're looking for is `forecast`, since you want to apply it to an arbitrary test building.

Comment: I ended up going with a variation on this solution, as I too could not find a way to pass panel data to `AutoReg()`. 

I used `train_df.stack().groupby(level=1)` to arrange my data in a single series. I then created a lag matrix for both training and testing data, using the `statsmodels.tsa.tsatools.lagmat` method. I appended my exogenous data to the resulting dataframe, and then fit it to a standard OLS model.

I'm quite surprised there is not a way to do this already, but I spent far too long on this in the first place.